# Error in creating instances of inherited classes

Tags: c#, oop, overriding

I have the following two classes

```
 public class A
 {
     public virtual decimal Sum(int x, int y)
     {
          return x+y;
     }
  }

 public class B : A
 {
      public override decimal Sum(int x, int y)
      {
           return x+y+1;
      }
 }
```

i write the following code in main class

```
  A myobj1;
  B myobj2;

  myobj1 = new B();
  myobj2 = new A();
```

Why the second object gives me error of `Cannot implicitly convert type 'ClassLibrary3.A' to 'ClassLibrary3.B'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` however `class B` inherits `class A`

Comment: You've tagged this as a Java question. What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Yes, but does A inherit from B?  You're trying to assign an A to a B after all.

Comment: its a generic question in `OOP`, so both languages will be related to it

Answer (score 3):

> however class B inherits class A

That means that all `B`s are `A`s.
It does not mean that all `A`s are `B`s.

Answer (score 1):

Let's re-write this using more meaningful names, just for clarity's sake: (The method isn't really relevant to this problem, I've omitted it,)

```
public class Animal
{
}

public class Person : Animal
{
}
```

---

```
Animal animal;
Person person;

animal = new Person();
person = new Animal();
```

The person is an animal. The animal isn't a person.

Comment: +1... also I'd use more traditional `Cat` instead of `Person` in the sample... Not every "person is animal" some are a bit nicer :).